# How to provide access to an EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to provide access to an EKS cluster.

From what I understood, I should be doing it with the aws-auth configmap.
My aws-auth config map looks like this:

```
Name:         aws-auth
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: auth
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default

Data
====
mapRoles:
----
- rolearn:  arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxxx
 username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
 groups:
   - system:bootstrappers
   - system:nodes
- rolearn:arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/AWSReservedSSO_DevAccountAdmin_xxxxxx
 username: admin
 groups:
   - system:masters
   - system:nodes
   - system:bootstrappers
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/AWSReservedSSO_DevAccountAccess_xxxx
  username: admin
  groups:
   - system:masters
   - system:nodes
   - system:bootstrappers
```

Note that this is the output of `kubectl describe cm -n kube-system aws-auth`
This seems to work usually. But for some reason, doing the same is not working for one of my developers.
Gives the error: `You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`

This has got to be the most complicated subject I've come accross wrt kubernetes despite the simplicity of the topic. Please help.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/amazon-eks-cluster-access/

Comment: @gohm'c I've done this already. Works usually. But doesn't work for some.